# Using LIMIT's during one-to-many relationship Queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the two tables `tabA` and `tabB`, and there is a one-to-many relationship from `tabA` to `tabB`. I have the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tabA` LEFT JOIN `tabB` ON `tabA`.`aID` = `tabB`.`aID`
```

and the rows that are returned is a large set with multiple duplicates from `tabA` for each `tabB` reference to `tabA`.

I am aware that I can use `GROUP BY` to limit the `tabA` rows to unique elements, unless I use custom field(s) using the `GROUP_CONCAT` function, combined with two `REPLACE` functions for escaping (which seriously impacts performance), I loose all bar one of the rows contained in `tabB`. An example query looks like:

```
   SELECT `tabA`.*,
          GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(REPLACE(`tabB`.`tabBCol1`, '/', '//'), ',', '/,')) AS `tabBCol`,
          GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(REPLACE(`tabB`.`tabBCol2`, '/', '//'), ',', '/,')) AS `tabBCo2` 
     FROM `tabA` 
LEFT JOIN `tabB` ON `tabA`.`aID` = `tabB`.`aID` 
 GROUP BY `tabA`.`aID`
```

That query will allow me to use the `LIMIT` syntax so I can (for example) only show 5 entries, starting after 5 (i.e. `LIMIT 5,5`). And when I apply that to the former query, then I won't get the next 5 queries, but a random set of data based on the numbers of associations.

So, apart from the second query, is there any way that I can fetch the rows, with there associations, but allow the use of the `LIMIT` syntax, and without the performance hit of excessive `REPLACE` functions?

**ADDITIONAL**

Although I can use multiple subqueries for each row, using the first query with `GROUP BY` syntax (which would allow me to apply any `WHERE` conditions for the associations), I am trying to find a way to avoid the N+1 Selects Problem (although in this example, my `LIMIT` syntax is `LIMIT 5,5`, I will be applying this to much larger `LIMIT`s (upto 1000 rows at a time)).

Comment: Two things jump out at me.  One, why are you doing a left join instead of an inner join.  Two, instead of select * why not, select distinct just the fields you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try two queries:

```
// get those 5 records
SELECT * FROM Cars   WHERE some_conditon = blabla LIMIT 5;

// get all associated records from related table
SELECT * FROM Wheels WHERE car_id IN (1, 3, 5, 123, 16);
```

In the result there will not be any N problem as you will always have two queries. Even if you will have 1000 records in 1st query it will always be better to use this simple method, than joins/groups by/concats/etc.

Comment: With the `IN` condition, when it gets to the sizes of 1000, how does that impact the performance?

Comment: Also may be your current ORM always allow you to work in this way. If not -- you can expand it into this direction.

Comment: It's a custom ORM, I am building it as an academic exercise. I believe the only way to truly understand a system is to be able to build one from scratch yourself that contains all the desired features

Comment: Less than any other methods. Anyway DATA, that you will get will be always MORE than query, that you will send. Simple operations costs less CPU.

Comment: I am more focused on using less CPU over RAM and Bandwidth

Comment: But don't trust me -- try by yourself :) EXPLAIN ... SQL_NO_CACHE

Comment: Then it should be your direction. But anyway, try it, try another mehtods. May be you will find something even better in the combination of some two/three methods.

Comment: Fair enough, cheers bud, using 2 queries is way better than using 1 + 1000 queries, perhaps less CPU, but in the grand scheme of things, better